# Mesh disappearing/moving during playback

Tags: mesh, keyframes

I rendered the animation, but the human body stays in the same place, this is only happening during object mode. How is it disappearing? Why did the eyes move down when there's no keyframes? I only have keyframes for the blue ball. I've also checked the dope sheet.

I don't know how else to fix this, please help! Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Could you please show the shaders for the different objects?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @BentleyCarpenter is this what you're looking for? (model on left, ball on right) https://imgur.com/a/9YaU4Hj